Can't solve this Dafny problem about implementing a O(n) algorithm
predicate Asc(a: array<int>)
  reads a
{
  forall i,j:: 0<=i<j<a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]
}

method occursInBoth(a: array<int>, b: array<int>) returns (r : bool)
  requires Asc(a) && Asc(b)
  ensures r == (exists i,j:: 0 <=i<a.Length && 0<=j<b.Length && a[i]==b[j])
{
  ... // implement yourself
}

The predicate Asc sorts any array into ascending order. This means the method should find if 2 seperate lists (in ascending order) have the same element. If they have the same element we should return True if not return False.
Question: Implement the method occursInBoth such that the call occursInBoth(a,b) performs
at most a.Length + b.Length computation steps.
Here is my unsuccessful attempt as solving the question.
predicate Asc(a: array<int>)
  reads a
{
  forall i,j:: 0<= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]
}

method occursInBoth(a: array<int>, b: array<int>) returns (r : bool)
  requires Asc(a) && Asc(b)
  ensures r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j])
{
  var i := 0;
  var j := 0;

  while i < a.Length && j < b.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length && 0 <= j <= b.Length
  {
    if a[i] < b[j] {
      i := i + 1;
    } else if a[i] > b[j] {
      j := j + 1;
    } else {  // a[i] == b[j]
      return true;
      assert r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j]); // This assertion holds
    }
  }
  return false;
  assert r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j]); // This assertion doesn't hold
}


There are several non-trivial reasoning required when r is false.
First observe that your while loop might terminate without seeing all
elements of either a or b (but not both), when r is false.
In final assert it is reasoning over all elements of a and b. For us
humans it is possible to connect various logical steps required to prove
final assert. But for Dafny it is not still.
Let's change such that Dafny see through all elements of a and b
 while i < a.Length || j < b.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length && 0 <= j <= b.Length
  {
    if i == a.Length {
      j := j + 1;
    }
    else if j == b.Length {
       i := i + 1;   
    }
    else if a[i] < b[j] {
      i := i + 1;
    } else if a[i] > b[j] {
      j := j + 1;
    } else {  
      return true;
    }
  }

Now it is complaining that loop might not terminate. Let's add decreases clause.
 while i < a.Length || j < b.Length
    decreases a.Length + b.Length - i - j
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length && 0 <= j <= b.Length

Still no luck. May be it needs loop invariant so that it can reason beyond loop statement. Let's add invariant which we believe is true.
while i < a.Length || j < b.Length
    decreases a.Length + b.Length - i - j
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length && 0 <= j <= b.Length
    invariant !(exists m, n:: 0 <= m < i && 0 <= n < j && a[m] == b[n])

Now using loop invariant it verifies method post condition but it has hard time reasoning through loop invariant. Establishing that requires some further steps which is along the line of invariant proof in this blog post. Have fun !

I have adjusted the code you provided with the help of the blog post. It works brilliantly. I will be posting it soon. Much obliged.

The correct answer was:
predicate Asc(a: array<int>)
  reads a
{
  forall i,j:: 0<= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]
}

method occursInBoth(a: array<int>, b: array<int>) returns (r : bool)
  requires Asc(a) && Asc(b)
  ensures r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j])
{
  var j, i := 0, 0;

  while i < a.Length || j < b.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length && 0 <= j <= b.Length
    invariant (forall m, n :: (0 <= m && 0 <= n && ((m < i && n < b.Length) || (m < a.Length && n < j))) ==> a[m] != b[n])
    decreases (a.Length + b.Length) - (i + j)

  {
    if i == a.Length {
      j := j + 1;
    } else if j == b.Length {
      i := i + 1;
    } else if a[i] > b[j] {
      j := j + 1;
    } else if a[i] < b[j] {
      i := i + 1;
    } else {
      return true;
      assert r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j]);
    }
  }

  return false;
  assert r == (exists i, j:: 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < b.Length && a[i] == b[j]);
}

